# coverting list of string coordinates into list of coordinates without string

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, arraylist

I have a list

```
flat_list =['53295,-46564.2', '53522.6,-46528.4', '54792.9,-46184', '55258.7,-46512.9', '55429.4,-48356.9', '53714.5,-50762.8']
```

How can I convert it into

```
[[53295,-46564.2], [53522.6,-46528.4], [54792.9,-46184], [55258.7,-46512.9], [55429.4,-48356.9], [53714.5,-50762.8]]
```

I tried

```
l = [i.strip("'") for i in flat_list]
```

nothing works.

```
l = [i.strip("'") for i in flat_list]
```

```
coords = [map(float,i.split(",")) for i in flat_list]
```

```
print(coords)
```

gives me <map object at 0x7f7a7715d2b0>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why complicate things?

Without any builtins such as `map` and `itertools`, this approach with a nested `list` comprehension should be a relatively simple and efficient one.

```py
flat_list = ['53295,-46564.2', '53522.6,-46528.4', '54792.9,-46184', '55258.7,-46512.9', '55429.4,-48356.9',
             '53714.5,-50762.8']

result = [float(f) for pair in flat_list for f in pair.split(',')]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[53295.0, -46564.2, 53522.6, -46528.4, 54792.9, -46184.0, 55258.7, -46512.9, 55429.4, -48356.9, 53714.5, -50762.8]
```

To instead end up with a *list* of *list*s, you can change the order of the `for` statements and then add braces around the sub-list for each `str.split` result, as shown below:

```py
flat_list = ['53295,-46564.2', '53522.6,-46528.4', '54792.9,-46184', '55258.7,-46512.9', '55429.4,-48356.9',
             '53714.5,-50762.8']

result = [[float(f) for f in pair.split(',')] for pair in flat_list]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[53295.0, -46564.2], [53522.6, -46528.4], [54792.9, -46184.0], [55258.7, -46512.9], [55429.4, -48356.9], [53714.5, -50762.8]]
```

Comment: your response is correct, my question was a bit wrong, because I want to convert into list of arrays for 2d coordinates. my previous question was with some space after the " ' "

Comment: updated the answer after the most recent edit in the question above.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit after your comment:** to get a list of lists you can use

```
list2 = [[float(f) for f in el.split(",")] for el in flat_list]
```

or

```
list2 = [list(map(float,el.split(","))) for el in flat_list]
```

**Deprecated:** If you are okay with 2 operations instead of a one-liner, go with:

```
list2 = map(lambda el: el.split(","), flat_list)
list3 = [float(el) for sublist in list2 for el in sublist]
```

or

```
import itertools
list2 = map(lambda el: el.split(","), flat_list)
list3 = list(map(float, itertools.chain.from_iterable(list2)))
```

Comment: thanks! your response is correct, my question was a bit wrong, because I wanted to convert into list of arrays for 2d coordinates. my previous question was with some space after the "," for each string. Please see my edited question

Answer (score 0):

I see that the coordinates come in pairs, so in order to convert them to an integer or float first we need to split them so they become single numbers.

```
    flat_list =['53295,-46564.2', '53522.6,-46528.4', '54792.9,-46184', '55258.7,-46512.9', '55429.4,-48356.9', '53714.5,-50762.8']
coordinates = []
for pair in flat_list:
    coordinates.extend(pair.split(','))
result = [float(x) for x in coordinates]
```

This is not the shortest way to do it, but I think it does the job.

Comment: thanks! your response is correct, my question was a bit wrong, because I want to convert into list of arrays for 2d coordinates. my previous question was with some space after the "," of each string. please see the edited question

Comment: Oh! In that case what marko suggested would also be my answer. Good luck!